# pandas.read_csv not erroring on a bad line with extra columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

As far as I can tell, **this only occurs if the bad line is the first line of data**

I have a simple csv file like so:

```
ownername,streetno,streetname
me,320,main st,just,absolute,garbage
you,40,mint ave
```

The command I'm using to read the file is

```
read_csv(file,',',header=0, quotechar=None, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, index_col=False)
```

As long as the extra values (just,absolute,garbage) occur on the first row of data, it will parse the file without errors, giving me the below DataFrame

```
  ownername  streetno streetname
0        me       320    main st
1       you        40   mint ave
```

That's not the worst result, but for what I'm working on, I'd prefer to error on any mismatch between the number of column headers and the number of data columns. Setting `error_bad_lines=True` had no effect.

Am I missing something here? Is this intended behavior? If it is intended behavior, is there any way to bypass it or make it more strict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>`error_bad_lines` is true by default which is what causes the exception to be raised. If you set it to `False`, it will skip the erroneous lines.</strike>

I have also found from my testing that truncation of bad data only occurs on the first line. May be worth [creating an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

Comment: The problem in the question is that no error is raised when reading the csv file. As stated, setting `error_bad_lines=True` has no effect (since, as you pointed out it is True by default).

Comment: Just realized I never updated back here: I have submitted a bug ticket https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40333